# Why is Wire.endTransmission(true) returning 10?

Tags: i2c, arduino-motor-shield

## Question:

The follow code is printing 10 over and over again (with spaces in between). I have an I2C device connected at `0x60`, and nothing connected at `0x61`. I'm confused by this because the [Wire.endTransmission(bool)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireEndTransmission) docs say the only valid return types are 0,1,2,3, and 4. These return types are further supported by the [Wire.endTransmission()](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/3a36501d6d67df41b24b4ec075f47a79586badc9/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp#L141), and the source code of the [twi_writeTo](https://github.com/panStamp/arduino_avr/blob/1160c70488d4962abb3901a800e577938d7e6ec0/libraries/Wire/utility/twi.cpp#L178) function calls.

### Code:

```

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Adafruit Motorshield v2 - DC Motor test!");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  shieldConnected(0x60);
  Serial.println("\n");
  shieldConnected(0x61);

  delay(2000);

}

/** 
 * Checks if an I2C device is connected at shieldAddr. This effectively checks if a 
 * motor shield exists at that location.
 * 
 * Note, this only works when everything's imported for some reason.
 */
void shieldConnected(uint8_t shieldAddr){
  Wire.beginTransmission(shieldAddr);
  Wire.write(1);
  uint8_t end = Wire.endTransmission(true);
  //shieldAddressValidator(shieldAddr);
  Serial.println(end);
}
```

```

Comment: Which arduino board do you use? Is that a working sketch? Are there spaces in between or new lines? Can you print it as a int.

Comment: Genuino 101, Yes, yes, and I can change it to printf if that's what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have bad news. The Arduino/Genuino 101 uses a Intel processor and it was a shame. There are different parts (serial, i2c) that never became fully compatible. There might be no solution to your problem or any problem with the 101. Buy a normal board that is compatible with the adafruit motor shield v2.